# HttpClient 2.0. Params "codified"

Tags: java, ascii, httpclient

I have to use HttpClient 2.0 (can not use anything newer), and I am running into the next issue. When I use the method (post, in that case), it "codify" the parameters to the Hexadecimal ASCII code, and the "spaces" turned into "+" (something that the receiver don't want).

Does anyone know a way to avoid it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even your browser does that, converting *space* character into +. See here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

It encodes URL, converts to UTF-8 like string.

> When encoding a String, the following rules apply:
>
> - The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0" through "9" remain the same.
> - The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
> - The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
> - All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte. The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform is used.

Also, see here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

> 1. Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A').
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by`&'.

---

To answer your question, if you do not want to encode. I guess, [URLDecoder.decode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) will help you to *undo* the encoded string.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I am capturing traces, and it looks like the receiver like it only when it is not encoded. But thanks for the info, it is good to read all that :-)

Comment: There is nothing "UTF-8 like" about % encoding.

Comment: @Stephen C I didn't get you. Doesn't the doc says, "The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8. However, for compatibility reasons, if an encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform is used." if you use the non-deprecated method, you have to mention encoding, which ideally should be UTF-8. So, all the encoded characters are UTF-8 preceded by a % and that's why I used word, 'utf-8 like'. Another reason is not everything converted to UTF-8, it's an amalgam of restricted letters and UTF-8

Comment: I understand your confusion.  However, there are two "encoding" steps.  First there is the replacement of reserved characters and spaces with %xx and +.  (Strictly speaking, this is escaping rather than encoding.)  This is what the OP is asking about, what I'm talking about, and what your answer should be talking about.  The output of this step is not "UTF-8 like".  Following that, the characters are encoded for transmission into UTF-8 (recommended) or some other character encoding - often Latin-1.  The output of the second step might be real UTF-8 ... or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could in theory avoid this by constructing the query string or request body containing parameters by hand.

But this would be a **bad thing** to do, because the HTML, HTTP, URL and URI specs all *mandate* that reserved characters in request parameters are encoded.  And if you violate this, you may find that server-side HTTP stacks, proxies and so on reject your requests as invalid, or misbehave in other ways.

The correct way to deal with this issue is to do one of the following:

- If the server is implemented in Java EE technology, use the relevant servlet API methods (e.g. `ServletRequest.getParam(...)`) to fetch the request parameters.  These will take care of any decoding for you.
- If the parameters are part of a URL query string, you can instantiate a Java URL or URI object and use the getter to return you the query with the encoding removed.
- If your server is implemented some other way (or if you *need* to unpick the request URL's query string or POST data yourself), then use URLDecoder.decode or equivalent to remove the % encoding and replace +'s ... after you have figured out where the query and parameter boundaries, etc are.